# moving the list of files with robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to move some files from one place to another with saving of directory. Result of my script is broken encoding and it doesn't work. I use robocoby, because I have files with names more 256 simbols. I need to move files from different locations. And we are talking about several hundred files.

```
$source = Get-Content "C:\Users\bill\Downloads\111.TXT" -Encoding UTF8

$destination = "C:\Users\bill\OneDrive\Documents"

foreach($file in $source)
    {
    robocopy $file $destination /MOVE /E /copyall /log:C:\Users\bill\OneDrive\Documents\log.txt
    }
```

Comment: We cannot see what is in your `C:\Users\bill\Downloads\111.TXT` file. Does that contain **full, absolute** paths to files, each on a separate line?

Comment: in C:\Users\bill\Downloads\111.TXT  :    C:\Users\bill\Downloads\0522.xlsx
C:\Users\bill\Downloads\2022-05-07 15-32-48.JPG  each on a separate line

Comment: robocopy can't move files. use this if you want to move folders:                        
$source = Get-Content "\\...\move.txt" -Encoding UTF8
$destination = "\\...\01"
foreach($file in $source)
    {
    $var =split-path "$file" -leaf
    $destination = $destination + '\' + $var
    robocopy "$file" "$destination" /MOVE /E /copy:DATSOU /log:"\\...\LOG.txt"
    }

Answer (score 0):

Jane,

Try building your robocopy command like this:

*** UPDATED and TESTED ***

```
Clear-Host

$source = Get-Content "G:\Test\111.txt" -Encoding UTF8

$destination = "G:\BEKDocs\Test"

Foreach ($SrcPath in $source) {

  $file     = Split-Path -Path $SrcPath -Leaf
  $path     = Split-Path -Path $SrcPath -parent
  $PLen     = $Path.Length -3
  $PAdd     = $Path.Substring(3,$PLen)
  $SavePath = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $PAdd

  $robocopyOptions = @('/Move', '/copyall')
  $LogFile         = 
        @('/log+:G:\BEKDocs\Transfer\log.txt')

  $CmdLine = @($path, $SavePath, $file) + 
               $robocopyOptions + $LogFile

  & 'robocopy.exe' $CmdLine

} #End Foreach
```

Note: Use single quotes as indicated!

Update notes:

- Part of the problem was that you had the filenames attached to the paths in your file where RoboCopy wants SourcePath DestPath FileSpec as the first three arguments.
- You're copying single files so there is no need for the Recurse /E parameter.
- Since you want to preserve the directory structure you need to append the Source path, less the drive (d:) to your destination directory.
- You're also calling RoboForm in a loop so you need the /Log+ parameter so each file is appended to the file rather than over writing it.

In my test I copied a file from the base directory, another from one level deep and a third from 2 levels deep. The code preserved the directory structure starting with the specified Destination as the Base or Root directory.

Took a bit of time to figure all this out but I wasn't going to let it go. Hope this works for you!

Comment: it doesn't work( the result of this script is path to log.txt (x2). I tried to delete line with logfile from script, but i get only broken encoding again

Comment: Jane see my updated solution above.